# How to upgrade Material Design Lite js components when using Angular routes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design-lite

I know MDL js components (like textfields, menus and tabs) are loaded and upgraded by default on document load, but it doesn't happen on templates when using angular routes. At this point, I'm using this, but it just makes my component works properly when the user visits the view by the second time:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() { 

   $document.ready(function() {
      componentHandler.upgradeDom();
   });

});
```

There is anyway to upgrade the component on the template before the user enter the view for the first time, or something like that? I'm stuck in this issue.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with MDL, but you might find [this](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1175) or [this](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1165) useful.

Comment: I'll take a look. Thank you very much @SeanWalsh.

Comment: I found a simple solution for my case, @SeanWalsh, thanks to you. 

Instead using $document.ready, I used just a setInterval(), just like that: 

      `code`  setInterval(function() {
            componentHandler.upgradeDom();
        }, 200); 
       `code`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
angular.module(...)
.run(function($rootScope, $location, $timeout) {
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
        });
    });
})
```